# Dapper Stored Procedures Zero Conversion

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dapper

I am using Dapper & ASP.NET Core to execute a stored procedure and return a dataset that will contain some negative values in the set.  What I am encountering is that when I execute the procedure and fill the model, all negative numbers are converted to 0, which is not what I want (the application's intent is to allow users to spot the negative values and correct them).  Out of curiosity I went and created a webforms application to make sure it wasn't something weird going on with my stored procedure.  I was able to execute the procedure and see that everything is returned as expected to the gridview in the webforms application.

What am I doing wrong?  Is it something that I have defined in my model that would tell it to convert negative values to 0?  The model is as shown below:

```
public class ScadaErrorModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Scada Error ID")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    //[Display(Name = "Location Description")]
    //public string Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Scada Link")]

    public string Scada_link { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Area")]
    public string Bwp_Area { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Asset Number")]
    public string Assetnum { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Asset Description")]
    public string Asset_Description { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Reading Date")]
    public DateTime Reading_date { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Region")]
    public string Bwp_region { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Error Type")]
    public string Error_type { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Comments")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Operating Hours")]
    public float Operating_hrs { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Downtime Hours")]
    public float Ttl_downtime_hrs { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Compressor Cylinder Oil Usage (gal)")]
    public float Oil_to_comp_cyl { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Crankcase Oil Usage (gal)")]

    public float Oil_to_cc_hand { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Crankcase Auto Oil Usage (gal)")]
    public float Oil_new_cc_ren { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Power Cylinder Oil Usage (gal)")]
    public float Oil_to_pwr_cyl { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Electricity Usage (kWh)")]
    public int Electricity_used { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Fuel Consumed (mcf)")]
    public float Fuel_consumed { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Horsepower Hours")]
    public int hrspwr_hrs { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "RPM - Average Engine Speed")]
    public int avg_unit_rpm { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Start Attempts")]
    public int Engine_starts_attempts { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Start Successes")]
    public int Engine_starts_success { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Start Failed")]
    public int Engine_starts_failed { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Startup Duration (min)")]
    public float Startup_duration { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Throughput/Capacity (mmscf)")]
    public float Thruput_mmcf { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is it the `int`s or the `float`s that are being mapped to 0?

Comment: Can you post the stored proc also?

Comment: And maybe the Dapper call. The model looks fine, so I suspect the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: @Michael Look at the db value, put a breakpoint where the query runs, see what comes out.  If the actual db value is not 0 but the result Dapper retrieves _is_ zero then somehow Dapper mapped the value to 0.  Most of the time I've seen this is because the variable types don't match up quite right.  That's why I asked if it was the ints or the floats.

Comment: I brought down the source code for Dapper so I could put in breakpoints and see where the transformation is occurring. I can see where the procedure is executing properly, and can see the negative values coming from the DB. But when it gets to this method in the SQLMapper class -- IEnumerable<T> QueryImpl<T> -- specifically in line 1101 that reads 

        object val = func(reader) 

that the value changes. Up to that point, I can break on the reader and see the that everything is ok. After is passes that line I see it changed to 0, but don't understand why the change occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion by @nurdyguy I was able to figure out what was going on.  I took a closer look at the model and then at the database.  There have been several changes to the database since I wrote the class for the model.  Most of them were minor, but a couple were changes to the underlying datatype of columns in the table I am accessing.  Once I fixed the differences in the model, everything started working.  Thanks again for everyone's help.